# How to place the value of an array into a table with OOP in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I'm building a chess game that randomly places 7 Queens on the board without hitting each other. The board is constructed of 7 rows and 7 columns.

I already know how to place the Queen in the array. But now I'm trying to plot the chessboard (with the method showBoard in the class Game) and the values of the "box" array in it. So, when the array changes, it should be reflected on the chessboard. Below the code and the array. Anyone an idea how to do this?

Index

```
<?php

require_once '../core/init.php';

/* Init $game */
$game = new Game();

/* Init board */
$game->setBoard(7);

/* Set piece */
$game->setPiece();

/* Show chessboard (including real-time status of the boxes) */
echo $game->showBoard();

/* Debug tool */
echo "<pre>";
print_r($game);
echo "</pre>";
```

Game class

```
<?php

/**
 * This class will handle:
 *  1) Setting up the board.
 *  2) Set a piece.
 *  3) Connecting to the Board class
 *  4) Show the chessboard (including real-time status of the boxes).
 */
class Game {
    private $_board;
    private $_length;
    private $_queen;

    /**
     * This method 1) will:
     *  1) Initialize the board based on the length.
     *  2) Set the property $_length
     * @param $length
     */
    public function setBoard($length) {
        // Action 1)
        $this->_board = new Board($length);
        // Action 2)
        $this->_length = $length;
    }

    /**
     * This method 2) will:
     *  1) Pick a random box with the method setRandomColRow() from the class Board.
     *  2) Create a new property $box and store the random row and column in it.
     *  3) Check if the random box is empty.
     *  4) Create a new Queen object.
     *  5) Place the Queen in the random box.
     */
    public function setPiece() {
        // Action 1)
        $this->getBoard()->setRandomColRow();
        // Action 2)
        $box = $this->getBoard()->getBox($this->getBoard()->randomRow,$this- >getBoard()->randomCol);
        // Action 3)
        if($box == !null) {
            // Action 4)
            $this->_queen = new Queen();
            // Action 5)
            $this->getBoard()->getBox($this->getBoard()->randomRow,$this->getBoard()->randomCol)->setPiece($this->_queen);
        }
     }

    /**
     * This method 3) will:
     *  1) Return access to the board properties and methods.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBoard() {
        // Action 1)
        return $this->_board;
    }

    /**
     * This method 4) will:
     *  1) Create a table with rows and place it in the string $table_str.
     *  2) Create rows and columns basses on the length property and place it in the string $table_str.
     *  3) TODO: Place the value of box->piece in the table box.
     *  4) Return the string
     * @return string
     */
    public function showBoard() {
        // Action 1)
        $table_str = '<table border="1px">';
        $table_str .= '<tr>';
            // Action 2)
            for($row=1; $row <= $this->_length; $row++) {
                for($col=1; $col <= $this->_length; $col++) {
                    $table_str .= '<td height=100px width=100px bgcolor=#FFFFFF></td>';
                }
                $table_str .= '</tr>';
            }
            // Action 4)
            return $table_str;
    }
}
?>
```

Board class

```
<?php

/**
 * This class will handle:
 *  1) Constructing the boards boxes.
 *  2) Returning the property $_row.
 *  3) Returning the property $_col.
 *  4) Returning the property $_box.
 *  5) Setting random rows and columns.
 *  6) Returning all the related boxes.
 *  7) Returning the horizontal related boxes.
 *  8) Returning the vertical related boxes.
 *  9) Returning the diagonal related boxes.
 */
class Board {

    public $randomRow;
    public $randomCol;

    private $_box;
    private $_length;
    private $_row;
    private $_col;

    /**
     * This method 1) will:
     *  1) Set the $_length property.
     *  2) Create an array of new objects, Boxes based on the length of the rows and columns.
     * @param int $length
     */
    public function __construct($length) {
        // Action 1)
        $this->_length = $length;
        for($row=0; $row < $length; $row++){
            for($col=0; $col< $length; $col++){
                $this->_row = $row;
                $this->_col = $col;
                // Action 2
                $this->_box[$row+1][$col+1] = new Box($row+1, $col+1);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method 2) will:
     *  1) Return the $_row property.
     * @return int
     */
    public function getRow() {
        // Action 1)
        return $this->_row;
    }

    /**
     * This method 3) will:
     *  1) Return the $_col property.
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCol() {
        // Action 1)
        return $this->_col;
    }

    /**
     * This method 4) will:
     *  1) Return the $_box property based on the specified row and column.
     * @param $row
     * @param $col
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBox($row, $col) {
        return $this->_box[$row][$col];
    }

    /**
     * This method 5) will:
     *  1) Randomly choose a number within the rang from 1 to the $_length property and place it in the property $randomRow.
     *  2) Randomly choose a number within the rang from 1 to the $_length property and place it in the property $randomCol.
     *  3) Execute the MarkRelatedHorizontalBoxes method.
     *  4) Execute the MarkRelatedVerticalBoxes method.
     *  5) TODO: Execute the MarkRelatedDiagonalBoxes method.
     */
    public function setRandomColRow() {
        // STATIC RANDOM TEST NUMBER
        //mt_srand(123456);
        // Action 1)
        $this->randomRow = mt_rand(1, $this->_length);
        // Action 2)
        $this->randomCol = mt_rand(1, $this->_length);
        // Action 3)
        $this->MarkRelatedHorizontalBoxes();
        // Action 4)
        $this->MarkRelatedVerticalBoxes();
    }

    /**
     * This method 6) will: TODO: check if this method is doing the write things and where it is used
     *  1) Set the random column to property $col
     *  2) Set the random column to property $row
     *  3) Return the random box
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function relatedBoxes() {
        $col = $this->randomCol;
        $row = $this->randomRow;
        return $this->getBox($row,$col);
    }

    /**
     * This method 7) will:
     *  1) Create the related horizontal array
     *  2) Loop thew the array
     *  3) Get the box position and place and X in the box as piece
     *  4) TODO: Check if the box is empty
     */
    public function MarkRelatedHorizontalBoxes() {
        // Action 1)
        for($row = 0; $row < $this->_length; $row++) {
            $horizontalCells[$row+1] = $row+1;
        }
        // Action 2)
        foreach ($horizontalCells as $horizontalCel) {
            // Action 3)
            $this->getBox($horizontalCel,$this->randomCol)->setPiece("X");
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method 8) will:
     *  1) Create the related vertical array
     *  2) Loop thew the array
     *  3) Get the box position and place and X in the box as piece
     *  4) TODO: Check if the box is empty
     */
    public function MarkRelatedVerticalBoxes() {
        // Action 1)
        for($col = 0; $col < $this->_length; $col++) {
            $verticalBoxes[$col+1] = $col+1;
        }
        // Action 2)
        foreach ($verticalBoxes as $verticalBox) {
            // Action 3)
            $this->getBox($this->randomRow, $verticalBox)->setPiece("X");
        }
    }

    /**
     * TODO: This method 9) will: 
     *  1) Create the diagonal array
     *  2) Loop thew the array
     *  3) Get the box position and place and X in the box as piece
     *  4) Check if the box is empty
     * @return array
     */
    public function relatedDiagonalBoxes() {

    }
}
```

Box class

```
<?php

/**
 * This class will handle;
 *  1) Setting the $_piece property
 */
class Box {

    private $_piece;

    /**
     * This method 1) will:
     *  1) Set the $_piece property equal to the input value
     * @param $piece
     */
    public function setPiece($piece) {
        $this->_piece = $piece;
    }
}
```

Piece class

```
<?php

/**
 * This class will handle;
 */
class Piece {

}
```

Queen class

```
<?php

/**
 * This class will handle;
 *  1) Extending the piece class, and therefore inherit all methods and properties.
 */
class Queen extends Piece {

}
```

Array of objects to plot on the chessboard.

```
Game Object
(
    [_board:Game:private] => Board Object
        (
            [randomRow] => 5
            [randomCol] => 4
            [_box:Board:private] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [2] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [3] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [4] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => X
                                )

                            [5] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [6] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [7] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [2] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [3] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [4] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => X
                                )

                            [5] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [6] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [7] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [2] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [3] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [4] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => X
                                )

                            [5] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [6] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [7] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [2] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [3] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [4] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => X
                                )

                            [5] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [6] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [7] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => X
                                )

                            [2] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => X
                                )

                            [3] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => X
                                )

                            [4] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => Queen Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [5] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => X
                                )

                            [6] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => X
                                )

                            [7] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => X
                                )

                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [2] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [3] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [4] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => X
                                )

                            [5] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [6] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [7] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [2] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [3] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [4] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => X
                                )

                            [5] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [6] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                            [7] => Box Object
                                (
                                    [_piece:Box:private] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [_length:Board:private] => 7
            [_row:Board:private] => 6
            [_col:Board:private] => 6
        )
```

Comment: Have I understood you correctly: you want to call Game::showBoard() when somebody changes the board with Box::setPiece()?

Comment: That's correct. I also included the index page.

Comment: Why is box an own class? Make this one method part of class board or extend it. Then just call ::showBoard() in the function.

Comment: How do I access the array to use in the showBoard() method?

Comment: You can use one of the modifications of the [observer pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/php). But if the only place where you change the board is Game::setPiece() then you can simply call $this->showBoard() there.

Comment: That's what I was looking for thanks!